# obtain last word from a string in python

Tags: python

Suppose `str = 'UPPER(\"Sales\".\"PRODUCT_NAME\" )'` is my string and I want to get only `'PRODUCT_NAME'` (the last word) from this string. I have tried the below technique but it doesn't provide me the correct word as `'PRODUCT_NAME'`. How can I achieve this? Is there any easy way to achieve this using regular expressions?

```py
str='UPPER(\"Sales\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"PRODUCT_NAME\" )'
val=str.strip("(|)")
val=val.split('.')
val_final=val[-1].strip('"')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `re.findall` for a regex option, we can try:

```py
inp = 'UPPER(\"Sales\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"PRODUCT_NAME\" )'
output = re.findall(r'^.*\b(\w+).*$', inp)
print(output[0])   # prints PRODUCT_NAME
```

For an explanation of how this works, the regex pattern will match everything up to the final word boundary, followed by the final word.  We then access this match to print the result you want.

Comment: @WasifHasan ... the penalty paid for blindly copying the OP I guess ...

Answer (score 1):

The `strip()` method removes stuff from the ends of the string only, so you need to do this *after* extracting the last word (with additional characters you don't want):

```py
string = 'UPPER(\"Sales\".\"PRODUCTS\".\"PRODUCT_NAME\" )'
val_final = string.split('.')[-1].strip('" )')
```

Also, it's not a good idea to use `str` as a variable name, as it overwrites the builtin `str` type.

#### More info on `strip()`

This removes all characters provided from both ends of the string. I suspect that by `'(|)'` you mean `'('` or `')'`. Just write this as `split('()')`. In the above solution I've left out `'('` as it does not appear towards the end of the string. But `'"'` and `' '` does, so these I've included.